# Number of internal Kafka Connect topic partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Although the number of recommended partitions is set to 25, it is not clear the frequency, the # of messages that the connector will PUSH in to the topic.  Further, what is the logical reason for 25 partitions, why not 10.  Suppose, if we have just 2 worker instance in a distributed mode.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html

Comment: Not clear which topic (config, status, offsets) you are reffering to... There's nothing wrong with having more partitions than you need, and frequency doesn't (always) determine how many partitions to have

Comment: we do not see any document corresponding to the Internal topics, there are some recommendations but it is not clear why we need to keep it at that level (for e.g. # of partitions)

Comment: You don't need to. But there are no downsides of it being that high, and so there is no suggestion for changing it